# Meaning of とる in 迷惑かけとる

Tags: compound-verbs

> 「いつも迷惑かけとるのはわしの方なんじゃから」
>   Because when it comes to causing trouble, it's usually me. (my TL attempt)

I think I can insert an を to get 迷惑をかける = "to cause trouble". I've seen とる=取る appended to a few verbs adding a meaning of 'take'. In this case I can't see how 'take' would change the verb in any meaningful way. So, what is the function/meaning of とる here? How does the meaning change if I omit it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

かけとる here is a slurred form of かけておる、 just like 〜ておく slurs to 〜とく sometimes.

〜ておる is 'old-man speech' for 〜ている。 It's also used in Kansai dialect.

The sentence roughly translates to:

> It's usually me who's causing trouble anyway.

Comment: Old-man?  Kansai?  Really?  I have been saying ておる/とる since I was a toddler and I am definitely not from Kansai.

Comment: @l'électeur I do not know how they speak in Nagoya nor did I limit 〜ておる's occurrence to Kansai-ben nor old men; but the character user3856370 is asking about is clearly assigned 役割語 which is what I was referring to with the quoted 'old-man speech'

Comment: Would then this two とるs in  わしがなんぼ預けとる思うとるんじゃい  be part of the ておる?