# What does this conversation from a novel mean? 「よく命が続いとるなあ」 「いや、呆れたもんだよ」

Tags: meaning, translation, colloquial-language

> 「おまえ、よく命が続いとるなあ」
> 「これが生き甲斐でござる」
> 「とりあえず酒でも飲め。いや、呆れたもんだよ」店主が言った。
> 「奢ってくれるかい？」
> 「奢るとも」

> “You, よく命が続いとるなあ”
> “This is what I live for.”
> “Anyway, let’s have a drink.  いや、呆れたもんだよ” said the owner.
> “Is it on the house?”
> “Of course.”

The extract is from Morimi Tomihiko's novel, *The Eccentric Family*.

Comment: Should there be a break between 「酒でも飲め」 'have a drink' and 「いや、呆れたもんだ」? It sounds like two different people's dialogue. Also, it sounds like the patron is buying a drink for the proprietor, which would be the opposite of 'on the house'. Do you have a link or an image you can post?

Comment: ^ ん？「おまえ、よく命が続いとるなあ」「とりあえず酒でも飲め。いや、呆れたもんだよ」は店主が言ってるんでしょう？　「店のおごり」って聞かない？　おかしくないと思いますけど・・

Comment: Next time, please include your translation attempt or how you have grammatically analyzed the sentence in question. Otherwise people have to explain every possible point which may have confused you. Pasting a sentence and just saying "what does this mean" is [always frowned upon here](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/5010). In addition, please try not to ask more than one thing at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the guy who said 生き甲斐でござる did (or told) something risky and amazing in front of this 店主, whatever it is.

> よく命が続いとるなあ
>   It's surprising you're still alive! / How did you survive?

- よく is an adverb you can use to say "How dare you ～!" See: [善くも as opposed to よく](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5651/5010)
- 命が続く is a set phrase, "to survive", "to keep being alive".
- とる is a [contraction of ておる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010), which is [the same as ている](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26091/5010) here. See also: [Meaning of とる in 迷惑かけとる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34641/5010)
- な (なぁ) is a exclamatory sentence-end particle.

> いや、呆れたもんだよ
>   Oh well, I'm shocked / you amazed me / it's unbelievable.

- いや is just another way of saying "oh" here.
- 呆れる is "to be amazed", "to be shocked", etc.
- ものだ is used to express exclamation. See: [Function of に and meaning of ものだ in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17616/5010)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're getting tripped up by the verb.  続いとる is a contraction of 続いておる.  <s>I've been told that ～て・おる is a somewhat Kansai-ish version of the ～て・いる construction found in eastern Japanese.</s> ← Striking based on feedback from Chocolate.

Comment: でもこの会話全体に関西弁っぽさは全くないですし・・・（関東っぽい「～かい？」とかあるし。。）　「ござる」とかもあるし、昔っぽい感じか、役割語とかなんじゃないですかね・・

Comment: @Chocolate, 関西弁の誤った指摘以外は、いかがでしょうか。その部分を削除しましょうか。

Comment: 「続いとる」は、「続いておる」の音が縮まったものですけど、ここでは、「お前、よく命が続いているなあ」ってことだと思うんです。あと、質問者は「いや、呆れたもんだよ」のところもわからないみたいですよね。「いや」は感動詞で、「～もんだ」＝詠嘆の「～ものだ」の辺りを説明してあげたらどうでしょう（本来、翻訳依頼の質問って、ダメなんでしょうけど・・）

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi 「ておる」に関しては別にそれ自体は間違ってないですよ。ただ、関西だけでなく広く西日本の色んな所で使われてるだけで。