# だいぶ撒いとるしなあ means what?

Tags: translation

だいぶ - greatly?
撒く - spread?
しなあ - ?

UPDATE: the context is the following. It's a scene from anime 'Your name'. The mayor is giving a speech in front of an audience. Then the focus is moved to a couple of people standing in the back among the crowd. A man says, "He's going to be reelected anyway". A woman says back to him だいぶ撒いとるしなあ. In the subtitles it is translated as "I heard he's been dishing out the pork".
As far as I understand し here is used to creat a list? Like she's adding to the man's point. And なあ is just for emphasis? So "And (he's been) greatly spreading (rumors/lies?) (about himself?)

Comment: Can you provide any context? What comes before this? What is being discussed when this is said?

Comment: @AmericanUmlaut It is from the anime 君の名は. The mayor is giving a speech and a woman that is standing nearby says this phrase to another person. I think in the subtitles it is translated as "I heard he's been dishing out the pork." –

Comment: Please give some indication how much of this you understand and where exactly you're having problems. It would also be useful to give some more context (you can add your comment to the question body). A picture is also helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「だいぶ撒{ま}いとるしなあ。」

In the context of politicians running for elections (in small towns), 「撒{ま}く」 can usually mean just one thing -- **"to go around giving citizens/voters things that have monetary value"** in order to win their favor.  The original meanings of the word are "**to sprinkle**", "**to scatter**", etc., so one could see the connection.

「だいぶ」 is an intensifier.

「し」 is used to give an example.  In this case, it is one example of the reasons why he would be reelected.

「なあ」＝「な」.  This is a sentence-ender for a light kind of declaration that also functions to seek agreement from the listener.  It is similar to 「ね」 and 「ねえ」 in meaning.

Thus, an example translation would be something like:

**"He sure has done a great deal of handing out stuff around us, hasn't he?"**

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed and clear answer!

Comment: You didn't explain the ～とる part.

Comment: It's a contraction of ておる. See: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62222/26484